# Is it possible to insert image in mail using php?

Tags: php, phpmailer, html-email

I have a mail template which contains a description and one large image . But while adding image to mail template body it wont display when the mail open . It shown as below :

[image]

I have tried this code :

```
$message = "<html><head></head><body>";
$message .= "<img src='link-image.jpg' alt='' /></body></html>";
$headers = "From: $from_email";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But when sending a mail directly (Inserting image with insert option) , it shows directly when the mail receives. Can we get this similar functionality of inserting image ?

Comment: Use full path of the image to display image in mail.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments. 
You might want to make the image available by downloading it from your server.

So instead of

```
<img src='link-image.jpg' alt='' />
```

you would use

```
 <img src='https://DOMAIN.TLD/images/link-image.jpg' alt='' />
```

Where 'domain.tld' is your domain and 'images' is you public image path.